# struggling to get unique values in large dataset

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a large dataset that can't fit in memory with fields "function_name" and "trace" (and a couple of others). The traces are very long strings, and what I want to do is for each function_name, ensure there are no duplicate traces without running out of memory. I have tried the following:

```
df = pl.scan_parquet(Path("...", "dataset.parquet"))
df = df.unique(["function_name", "trace"]).sink_parquet(Path("...", "output.parquet"))
```

But I quickly get an out-of-memory error. What is the right way to do this? (If I were to do it sequentially, so filtering by function name then getting unique values, it will work but is just really slow).

Comment: What you have looks right. Are you using the latest version of Polars? The streaming engine is an on-going work, so that would be the first thing I would check for.

Comment: I have 0.19.15 which I believe is currently the latest version. Do you think this is a bug then?

Comment: 0.19.15 is the latest. If it's going OOM I think that would be classified as a "bug", yes.

Comment: In scan_parquet try setting `low_memory=True`.